# In boost file_sink class delay the open call

Tags: c++, boost

The function foo() returns 5 bytes from a file on every call to it. If **file_sink** class is used then the file has to be opened every time foo() is called. One way is to declare the file_sink as private in the header file and then in the constructor call the open on file_sink and on every call to foo() just call read w/o the necessity to open() every time. But this seems to be not possible since the file_sink constructor expects the file path. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `file_sink` pointer in the header file, initialize it to NULL in the constructor, and have `foo` create the `file_sink` (with a file name) the first time through.

Comment: Or make it `boost::optional<file_sink>` and avoid the dynamic allocation and associated memory management

Comment: @sehe - even better.  I tend to be old-school.